# Why does this not cause IndexOutBoundsError in java

Tags: java

In java,

```
String s = "a";
String ss = s.substring(1);
System.out.println(ss.length());
```

I was wondering why the code does not cause error, and the result shows the length of string ss is 0.

Comment: Habe you read the [documentation of `String::substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))?

Comment: `String t = "";` is legal. The empty `String` exists.

Answer (score 2):

Your string `"a"` has only 1 character at position `0`, so in `substring(int)` you should pass the *first position* where will a new string start until it ends. You passed `1`, but there's no character with position `1` in this string, but you won't get exception, because this function will return an empty string instead of throwing exception. If you need throwing exception, just check the length of the string:

Read docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

It will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or **larger than the length of this String object.**

string length of variable "s" is 1 and here you put beginIndex=1 which is not larger than the string length. That's why it is not throwing any kind of exception. Try with beginIndex=2, you will get an IndexOutOfBoundException.